# BitOperations does NOT exist in current context. C#, CMake, & VS Code

Tags: c#, cmake

I am using VS Code editor and CMake to create C# projects. Using System.Numerics.BitOperations produces a "CS0103" error: The name 'BitOperations' does not exist in the current context.

I added using System.Numerics to other import statements, that are equally included in the VS_DOTNET_REFERENCES target properties. What am I doing incorrectly? Using .NET 8. The code runs fine in Visual Studio, because I have buttons to add References.